# What is the difference between the following to methods for bind_param PHP

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm just getting over using the singleton approach and am starting to get into prepared statements... I'm racking my brain on why one version of this works and one does not when, to me, they seem to be the same thing... I really want it to work the second way in order to meet my end goal.

This works:

```
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), array("i", 2));
```

This does not:

```
$params = array("i", 2);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);
```

Comment: This is the thing I dislike most about *mysqli* and the reason PDO will always win out for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting an error message like

> mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in...

The problem is that `bind_param()` in PHP 5.3+ requires array values as reference while 5.2 works with real values.

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php):

> Care must be taken when using **mysqli_stmt_bind_param()** in conjunction with **call_user_func_array()**. Note that **mysqli_stmt_bind_param()** requires parameters to be passed by reference, whereas **call_user_func_array()** can accept as a parameter a list of variables that can represent references or values ([ref](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)).

---

One solution is to create an array of references

```
$params = array("i", 2);
$tmp = array();
foreach($params as $key => $value) {
    $tmp[$key] = &$params[$key];
}
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $tmp);
```

and another similar [solution](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#96770) is

```
function refValues($arr){ 
    if (strnatcmp(phpversion(),'5.3') >= 0) //Reference is required for PHP 5.3+ 
    { 
        $refs = array(); 
        foreach($arr as $key => $value) 
            $refs[$key] = &$arr[$key]; 
        return $refs; 
    } 
    return $arr; 
} 

$params = array("i", 2);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), refValues($params));
```

Comment: Amazing. I love the second solution!

Comment: +1 for giving insight to problem, I have got similar issue many times, but just maked a way to skip that, Can you please explain any reason why this prefered to pass as a reference over values,is there any reason to do same